# Using regex to put parentheses around a word

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm trying to use bash to fix some SVN commits that have math mode symbols because I made a magical SVN to LaTeX paper generator for my reports. I am trying to find anything with caret (`^`) in it and put `\(match\)` in it.

What I have so far:

```
MYVAR="This is not x^2 good without y^2x^3 extra latex brackets"
echo $MYVAR | sed -e '\b\w*([\^])\w*\b/g'
```

But I'm unclear how to take the multiple matches and put the `\(match\)`.
I would like the final string to be:

```
 "This is not \(x^2\) good without \(y^2x^3\) extra latex brackets"
```

Any examples would be appreciated.  I'm having some sort of mental block.

Comment: You want `\( \)`, right? Not forward slashes...?

Comment: @BenjaminW. yes, trying to get those parts into math mode, which is /( word /) or $$ word $$

Comment: I mean, ``\``, and not `/`, right?

Comment: You've updated it in one place, but two other occurrences are still `/( /)`.

Comment: @BenjaminW.  Thank you for noticing.  My Japanese keyboard likes ¥ and the control sequence sometimes gives me the / instead of \ if I'm not paying attention. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression such as `y^2x^3` can be described as "a `^` surrounded by groups of characters consisting of alphanumeric characters or more instances of `^`". With GNU sed (with the `-r` option so we don't have to escape too much), you can express this as

```
(\w|\^)+\^(\w|\^)+
```

or wordier, with bracket expressions (can't use `\w` in those)

```
[[:alnum:]^]+\^[[:alnum:]^]+
```

To put these between `\( \)`, we make a substitution to add the parentheses:

```
$ myvar="a^2 This is not x^2 good without y^2x^3 extra latex brackets b^5"
$ sed -r 's/(\w|\^)+\^(\w|\^)+/\\(&\\)/g' <<< "$myvar"
\(a^2\) This is not \(x^2\) good without \(y^2x^3\) extra latex brackets \(b^5\)
```

I've expanded the example slightly to show how it works at beginning or end of strings as well.

This is far from foolproof: it will gladly accept `^^^` and other nonsensical expressions.

To make this more portable, say POSIX sed compliant, we have to stick to basic regular expressions and can't use alternation or `+`:

```
sed 's/[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]^]*\^[[:alnum:]^]*[[:alnum:]]/\\(&\\)/g' <<< "$myvar"
```

This last expression requires a character other than `^` at the beginning and end of the match, so `x^2` would be fine, but `^2`, `2^` and `^^^` would not be matched.

The `&` in the substitution stands for the complete match, and the `\` have to be escaped to show up in the result.

Answer (score 2):

Not sed but you can use Perl:

```
echo "$MYVAR" | perl -pe 's/([\w^]+^[\w^]+)/\/\(\1\)\//g'
```

## Explanation

### Matching

```
(   # Start a capturing group
    [    # Start a character set
        \w    # Match words (alphanum & underscores)
        ^     # Match carets
    ]    # Close character set
    +    # Match 1 or more of previous token
    \^   # Match Escaped caret
    [    # Start a character set
        \w    # Match words (alphanum & underscores)
        ^     # Match carets
    ]    # Close character set
    +    # Match 1 or more of previous token
)   # Close capturing group
```

### Replacing

```
\/    # Escaped /
\(    # Escaped (
\1    # Captured token #1
\)    # Escaped )
\/    # Escaped /
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's,[^^[:space:]]*^[^[:space:]]*,\\(&\\),g'
```

`[^^[:space:]]*^[^[:space:]]*` will match any set of non-space characters containing at least one caret.

`\\(&\\)` The ampersand will be replaced by the entire match, encircling it in parenthesis.